# Finding mean of a values in a dictionary without using .values() etc

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like:

```
G={'E': 18.0, 'D': 17.0, 'C': 19.0, 'B': 15.0, 'A': 0}
```

I have to find the mean of the values e.g. mean(18,17,19,15,0) using a simple `for` loop without using built in functions like `.values()`, `.items()` and so on. I tried the following but am getting an error:

```
d=[float(sum(values)) / len(values) for key, values in G]
    return (d)   
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Can someone help me fix this????

Comment: I don't see the other answers meeting the constraints of your question, was what I did what you intended?

Comment: Based on your updated question with additional constraints, @AaronHall appears to have provided the right answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To do this with a "simple for loop", using your constraints against using the dict methods:

```py
G = {'E': 18.0, 'D': 17.0, 'C': 19.0, 'B': 15.0, 'A': 0}


count = 0
_sum = 0
for key in G:
    count += 1
    _sum += G[key]

print('this is the mean: ', _sum/count)
```

If you're supposed to avoid dict methods, clearly this is an academic exercise.

Without that constraint:

The `statistics` module in the standard library has a `mean` method, which would be my first thought (as the standard library does not require third party packages.):

```py
>>> G={'E': 18.0, 'D': 17.0, 'C': 19.0, 'B': 15.0, 'A': 0}
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> mean(G[k] for k in G)
13.8
```

Third party packages like numpy and pandas have objects with a `mean` method:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> array([G[k] for k in G]).mean()
13.8

>>> from pandas import Series
>>> Series([G[k] for k in G]).mean()
13.8
```

If we allow ourselves to use the `values()` method, this gets a little simpler with iterable unpacking. For some reason the other answers violate that condition, so I figure I should show the more efficient way of doing it:

```py
>>> Series([*G.values()]).mean()
13.8
```

Answer (score 16):

If you use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

np.array(list(dict.values())).mean()
```

Comment: It's interesting that this violates the contraints of the question - to avoid using dict methods.

Comment: insanely_sin's answer below is simpler: `np.mean(list(dict.values()))`

Answer (score 12):

```
import numpy as np
np.mean(list(dict.values()))
```

Comment: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 4):

Iteration over a dictionary iterates over its keys.  Try just using `for key in G`, and then using `G[key]` appropriately instead of `values`.

Alternatively, use the `iteritems()` method of the dictionary to get `key, value` pairs from G, i.e.:

```
d=[float(sum(values)) / len(values) for key, values in G.iteritems()]
```

(For the record, your actual method of computing a mean doesn't look right to me, but you may as well fix the iteration problem first).

Comment: is it possible to use this without inbuilt functions like .iteritems() ?

Comment: Sure, you use the first method I suggested where you use `for key in G` rather than `for key, values in G`, and then use `G[key]` to refer to the actual values.

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.4 upwards there is a very clear way:

```
import statistics
numbers = [G[key] for key in G]
mean_ = statistics.mean(numbers)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `G.values()` to get all the values from a dictionary.

```
G = {'E': 18.0, 'D': 17.0, 'C': 19.0, 'B': 15.0, 'A': 0}
d = float(sum(G.values())) / len(G)
print (d)
```

This prints `13.8`.

Note that there is a difference between Python 2 and Python 3 here. In Python 2, `G.values()` is a newly constructed list of values. In Python 3, it is a generator, which can be thought of as a “lazy list”. The same thing is called `G.itervalues()` in Python 2.

Comment: +1: This is quick and easy. Intuitive, too. Too bad `.values` is not what user wants.

Comment: can we do this without using .values() ??

Comment: @Rachel: sure, see other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You want:

```
mean = sum([G[key] for key in G])/float(len(G))
```

Your original code will also produce a:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

when you try to sum the values.

Comment: You don't really even need to use the `keys` list here.  You can just iterate directly over the keys of `G`, like: `sum([G[key] for key in G])/float(len(G))`

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest instead of the current answers is adopting a functional programming paradigm that is reusable and flexible. For example, creating a function to calculate any statistic on `list` values contained within a simple `dict`:

```
def summarize_dict(dictionary, function):
        dict_new = {}
    for k,v in dictionary.items():
        dict_new[k] = function(v)
    return dict_new
```

Testing:

```
import numpy as np

keys = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
values = [range(2),range(4),range(6),range(8),range(10)]
dictionary = dict(zip(keys, values))

summarize_dict(dictionary, np.mean)
```

Yields:

```
{'a': 0.5, 'b': 1.5, 'c': 2.5, 'd': 3.5, 'e': 4.5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another for-loop, this one not needing a counter for items.

```
G = {'E': 18.0, 'D': 17.0, 'C': 19.0, 'B': 15.0, 'A': 0}

sum = 0
for k in G:
    sum += float(G[k])

print "Mean: " + str(sum/len(G))
```

Results to:

```
Mean: 13.8
[Finished in 0.3s]
```

Actually, given your data, there's no need to use `float`. On my end, removing `float` and just leaving `sum += G[k]` still outputs the same since the values are not strings anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a dictionary with multiple keys, each having a list of values:

```
your_averaged_dictionary = {key: np.mean(values) for key, values in your_dictionary}
```